# I got this error java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

Tags: java, android

I try to evaluate the postfix String using the `EvalauatePostfix.class` and       `equal(View view)` method in `MainActivity` class.

when I press the button its give me following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the
>   activity
>
> at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3861

....................

```
    public class EvaluatePostfix {


        public String outEvaluatePostfix(String s){
            String in = s;
            String[]inArray =  split(in);
            int size = inArray.length;

            double ans = 0;

            Stack<Double> stack = new <Double> Stack();

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                String c = inArray[i];

                if (!checkOp(c)){
                    double cd = Double.parseDouble(c);
                    stack.push(cd);

                }else{

                    double op1 = stack.pop();
                    //double opd2 = (double) Character.digit(String.valueOf(op2),10);
                    double op2 = stack.pop();
                    //double opd1 = (double) Character.digit(op1,10);
    //                double ans1 = op2/op1;
                    if(c.equals("+")){
                        ans = op2+op1;
                        stack.push(ans);

                    }
                    if(c.equals("-")){
                        ans = op2-op1;
                        stack.push(ans);

                    }
                    if(c.equals("*")){
                        ans = op2*op1;
                        stack.push(ans);

                    }
                    if(c.equals("/")){
                        ans = op2/op1;
                        stack.push(ans);

                    }
                }


            }

            double outD = stack.pop();

            String out = String.valueOf(outD);

            return out;
        }


        public static String[] split(String s){

            String iString = s;

            String token [] = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < iString.length(); i++) {
                token = iString.split(" ");
            }
            return token;
        }

        public boolean checkOp(String c) {

            if (c.equals("+")||c.equals("-")||c.equals("/")||c.equals("*")){
                return true;
            }else
                return false;

        }

    }
```

..................

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    TextView textView;
    String input ="";
    EvaluatePostfix evaluatePostfix;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(input);
        evaluatePostfix = new EvaluatePostfix();

    }

    public void onClickNum(View view){
        Button b = (Button) view;
        input = input + b.getText();
        textView.setText(input);
    }

    public void onClickOp(View view){
        Button b = (Button) view;
        input = input + b.getText();
        textView.setText(input);
    }

    public void clear(View view){
        textView.setText("");
        input ="";
    }


    public void equal(View view){
        InfixToPostfix infixToPostfix = new InfixToPostfix();
        String out = infixToPostfix.outInfixToPostfix(textView.getText().toString());
        String ans = evaluatePostfix.outEvaluatePostfix(out);
        textView.setText(ans);
    }
```

**Edit:**
Full log

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the
>   activity
>   at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3861)
>                                                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4476)
>                                                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18822)
>                                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
>                                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
>                                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551)
>                                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:914)
>                                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:730)
>                                                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                                      at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3856)
>                                                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4476) 
>                                                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18822) 
>                                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808) 
>                                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103) 
>                                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
>                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551) 
>                                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:914) 
>                                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
>                                                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "58X8"
>                                                                                                      at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
>                                                                                                      at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:269)
>                                                                                                      at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
>                                                                                                      at
>   com.example.muhammadkashif.calculator.EvaluatePostfix.outEvaluatePostfix(EvaluatePostfix.java:24)
>                                                                                                      at
>   com.example.muhammadkashif.calculator.MainActivity.equal(MainActivity.java:49)
>                                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                                                      at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3856) 
>                                                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4476) 
>                                                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18822) 
>                                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808) 
>                                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103) 
>                                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
>                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551) 
>                                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:914) 
>                                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
>                                                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: probably null exception somewhere, please post full log

Comment: post the xml layout file to see which method get triggered on click

Comment: Which method is meant? Maybe the activity is not shown already so you got the illegal state...

Comment: As I think it's line: String out = infixToPostfix.outInfixToPostfix(textView.getText().toString());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log says: `Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException:` ... `java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295) at com.example.muhammadkashif.calculator.EvaluatePostfix.outEvaluatePostfix(EvaluatePostfix.java:24)` 
This basically means the string isn't of a format accepted by `Double.parseDouble`.
So probably you're not giving in a string of the format numbers and operators always separated by spaces to `outEvaluatePostfix`, and then they don't  get properly split which would cause such a mistake.

A other just suggestion thing for code cleanness:

```
    public static String[] split(String s){
        return s.split(" ");
    }
```